# How to programmatically differentiate between dvd or mini dvd disk inserted?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dvd

I need to get a capacity of inserted DVD disk.

DeviceIoControl function call with IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX parameter writes 4128768 bytes as a size of DVD what, obviously, is wrong result. Code was taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/calling-deviceiocontrol.

Another solution was to determine disk read or write speed via ckMMC lib's Device interface and return size depending on it's type. But it isn't reliable solution since speed can vary on different CD/DVD drives.

Maybe, I'm missing something with DeviceIoControl usage and it can return me correct result or there exists  better approach to calculate DVD disk's capacity.

Comment: No sure (never tried it) but perhaps [`IOCTL_DVD_READ_STRUCTURE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddcdvd/ni-ntddcdvd-ioctl_dvd_read_structure?redirectedfrom=MSDN) can help.

Comment: My understanding is that the CD or DVD has its capacity stored in the media.  The difficulty, is reading this block. :-(

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Thank You! [DVD_LAYER_DESCRIPTOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddcdvd/ns-ntddcdvd-_dvd_layer_descriptor) contains all necessary information. Pls, write your comment as answer, I'll accept it.  [Here](https://github.com/PCSX2/pcsx2/blob/master/plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/Windows/IOCtlSrc.cpp#L196) good example of it's usage.

Comment: @Borys Great that it worked out!, I think you know this better than I do, so please go ahead and make a detailed description of how to do this and put it up as an answer. It's totally ok to answer your own questions when you've figured something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a field `DiskSize` in [DVD_LAYER_DESCRIPTOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddcdvd/ns-ntddcdvd-_dvd_layer_descriptor), which I was looking for.

Firstly, we should open drive with correct permissions.

```
HANDLE drive = CreateFileW(devicePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, nullptr);
```

Be careful with `devicePath`, it should be in [Win32 Device Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-device-namespaces). After getting drive handle, with the help of [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol) get `DVD_LAYER_DESCRIPTOR` structure.

```
DWORD unused;
std::array<char, 22> buffer;
DVD_READ_STRUCTURE dvdReadStruct;
dvdReadStruct.Format = DvdPhysicalDescriptor;

DeviceIoControl(drive, IOCTL_DVD_READ_STRUCTURE, &dvdReadStruct, sizeof(dvdReadStruct),
                         buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &unused, nullptr))

DVD_LAYER_DESCRIPTOR layerDescription = *reinterpret_cast<DVD_LAYER_DESCRIPTOR *>(
        reinterpret_cast<DVD_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER *>(buffer.data())->Data);
CloseHandle(drive);
```

`dvdReadStruct.Format` determines which structure will be written to `buffer`. For example, if you will set `DvdManufacturerDescriptor`, function writes [DVD_MANUFACTURER_DESCRIPTOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddcdvd/ns-ntddcdvd-_dvd_manufacturer_descriptor) to buffer.